# How to retrieve value from a sheet that is named in a cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following Excel table:

```
|----------------|------------------------|
| SHEET NAME     | VALUE FROM SHEET       |
|----------------|------------------------|
| sheet1         | =’sheet1’!$A$12        |
| sheet2         | =’sheet2’!$A$12        |
| sheet3         | =’sheet3’!$A$12        |
| sheet4         | =’sheet4’!$A$12        |
... lots of other lines ...
```

But I would like the second column formula to retrieve the sheet name automatically from the first column. Some thing like this:

```
|----------------|------------------------|
| SHEET NAME     | VALUE FROM SHEET       |
|----------------|------------------------|
| sheet1         | =A2!$A$12              |
| sheet2         | =A3!$A$12              |
| sheet3         | =A4!$A$12              |
| sheet4         | =A5!$A$12              |
... lots of other lines ...
```

Unfortunately the formula `=A2!$A$12` does not work.

How would be the formula so that it would retrieve data from the sheet informed at a specified cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use `INDIRECT()` for this: For `B2`, use the formula `=INDIRECT("'" & A2 & "'!$A$12")`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `indirect` function in Excel, in this case if your cursor is on the first row in the "value from sheet" column selected, you can write in that cell:

```
=indirect("'"&a2&"'!$A$12")
```